# Get sum of matched string values in lua

Tags: lua

```
local currentTable ={
{apple = 2, mango = 3},
{apple = 3, mango = 7},
{apple = 1}}

local strings = {'apple', 'mango'}
local newTable = {}

local s = 0
function sum(str,data)
  for i, x in pairs(data) do
    if i == str then
        print(str)
        s = s + x
    end
  end
  return s
end

for k,v in pairs(currentTable) do
  if strings[k] then
    newTable[strings[k]] = sum(strings[k], v)
  end
end

for k,v in pairs(newTable) do
  print(k,v)
  --desired output: newTable = {apple = 6, mango = 10}
  --but it's giving me: newTable = {apple = 2, mango = 9}
end
```

I want to fill the newTable with the sum of specific key values.
Been doing this for hours but can't seem to make it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The local variable `s` should be inside your sum function or previous sums will affect it. `k, v in pairs(currentTable)` gives you `k` from `1` to `3`; `strings[k]` does not do what you think it does. You'd have to iterate over the table `v` and see for each key whether it is one of the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `currentTable` and `strings` are *array-like* tables. This means they have numerical indices, starting at 1 and ending with *N*, where *N* is the length of the table.

Very verbosely:

```lua
local currentTable = {
    [1] = {apple = 2, mango = 3},
    [2] = {apple = 3, mango = 7},
    [3] = {apple = 1}
}

local strings = {
    [1] = 'apple',
    [2] = 'mango'
}
```

The ***k**eys* in both tables are *numbers*. The ***v**alues* in `currentTable` are *tables*, and the ***v**alues* in `strings` are *strings*.

This loop

```lua
for k, v in pairs(currentTable) do
```

means that `strings[k]` is indexing `strings` with numerical indices based on `currentTable`. This is problematic because

```lua
if strings[k] then
    newTable[strings[k]] = sum(strings[k], v)
end
```

only attempts to sum *tables* (`v`) whose indices (`k`) exist in *strings*.

Basically, you are always skipping the third table in `currentTable` because `strings[3]` is `nil`.

---

`s` should be local to `sum`, otherwise it will keep its value from the previous calls to `sum`.

---

For every *string* in `strings` you should check each *table* in `currentTable` for a key that matches.

Consider the following cursory example:

```lua
local function sum(baskets, fruits)
    local result = {}

    -- for every fruit we are interested in
    for _, fruit in ipairs(fruits) do
        result[fruit] = 0 -- create the sum

        -- for every basket (collection of fruits)
        for _, basket in ipairs(baskets) do
            -- if the basket contains the currently interesting fruit
            if basket[fruit] then
                -- add its count to our current sum
                result[fruit] = result[fruit] + basket[fruit]
            end
        end
    end

    return result
end

local my_fruit_baskets = {
    { apple = 2, mango = 3 },
    { apple = 3, mango = 7 },
    { apple = 1 }
}

local interesting_fruits = { 'apple', 'mango' }

local total_fruits = sum(my_fruit_baskets, interesting_fruits)

for name, count in pairs(total_fruits) do
    print(name, count)
end
```

Result:

```
mango   10
apple   6
```

Comment: thanks dude, ill give it a try. im just a week old in learning lua and so much things to learn.

Comment: Is there a chance that it will just detect similar keys instead of relying on the strings?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but my first impression is *no*. For a table like `{ mango = 4 }`, that key is fully equivalent to `'mango'` (i.e., verbosely `{ ['mango'] = 4 }`). There should be no *chance* involved, unless you start programming in randomness ([`math.random`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.random)).